# SCARA Robot sending strange ASCII Characters

Tags: rs232

I am trying to send commands via a Serial COM Port (RS 232) to a TMB200 SCARA Robot's controller and when I connect it to my laptop and open hyperterminal the following random characters start showing up on the screen repetitively.

[image]

I have tried adjusting the baud rate and number of bits to all available options and while the type of characters being displayed changes, they do not become understandable. Does anyone know what the problem could be and how to fix it?

Comment: the data is probably binary ... if the pattern repeats, then the characters are not random

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Multiplier. I'll second what @jsotola said - your data is probably coming back in binary format. You need the protocol definition to be able to make sense of the returning data.

Comment: Hi guys and sorry for the later reply. Could you please elaborate on this a little bit? How do you know it is binary, shouldn't it just be 0s and 1s in that case? And what exactly do you mean by a protocol definition?